# How to mysqldump from the last dump?

Tags: mysql

What I try to do, is making a dump with `--single-transaction` and not stopping the website.
And then I want to import it (as it will take hours) without stopping the website.
Next, it would be really good if I can make a fast dump but only from the last one.
Like that I can stop the website, dump and import fast as it's a small one.

Thanks

Comment: So you want to dump only data that is new since the most recent dump?

Comment: Yes only data as the structure won't change. But some row can have change as well :(

Comment: mysqldump lets you use a query of sorts in the cmd line. If your data has info like a datestamp you could just select for data new/changed since a given date.

Comment: not all my table have, but the biggest one have and never change, only add new row so can be a first good idea to improve the dump. I will look for that, just hope I can export everything only not one table to don't have to write all tables ;) Thanks for the good idea.